# SQL basic date problems

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got 2 items in "our_videos" table, On column "datemade" one of their date is "2014-11-21 12:00:00", another one is "2014-11-22 12:00:00", I'm trying to select both of them(selecting monthly data) with this SQL command

```
SELECT * FROM our_videos WHERE YEAR(datemade) = YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(datemade)= MONTH(NOW())
```

And I get this:

> MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0004 sec)

What would be a proper way to SELECT this month data?

Comment: Selecting the right month could be useful. We're in december right now :)

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that current month is November? /sorry me being so slow to comment/

Comment: Oh I'm feeling soo stupid now, yeah I was thinking that this command is selecting last 30days, I'm Loughing so hard right now at my fooliness, thank you guys The shame is going to follow me forever now :D

Comment: No need to feel ashamed, if I felt ashamed each time I did something like that, I would feel rather depressed :)

Answer (score 0):

The current month is December, which is 12.  Is this what you want?

```
SELECT *
FROM our_videos
WHERE YEAR(datemade) = YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(datemade) = MONTH(NOW()) - 1;
----------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

By the way, if you rephrase the `where` clause, the query can use an index:

```
WHERE datemade >= date_sub(date_sub(date(now()), interval day(now()) - 1 day), interval 1 month)
      datemade < date_sub(date(now()), interval day(now()) - 1 day)
```